# How can I use Input in Popup using Vimscript?

Tags: input, vim, popup

I'm learning Vimscript and I've learned about Popup but I want to know how I can use Input in Popup for example as in the Coc Plugin when using the Coc-rename function.

[image: Like this]

Comment: 1. Are you sure that screenshot was taken in Vim to begin with? 2. Did you consider reading through `:help popup` and experimenting along the way?

Comment: Yes, that's Vim I did this Screenshot. Yes, I read `:help popup` and I didn't find the way to do that. I experimented and learned how to do other cool things with a popup but not that.

Comment: If you read `:h popup` then you should've read at least `:h popup-intro`, as it's the first thing there.